# Join strings using Liquid

Tags: string, jekyll, liquid, static-site

In the code below, I am trying to set style properties on the element. I have inherited someone else's code so an not clear on two things:

1 - Why is the Liquid object `'{{ new.image }}'` wrapped in quotes/
2 - How can I join the string value of width & height in the below code with `px`. The below code is incorrect.

```
{% for news in page.carousel %}
  {% assign width = 1920 %}
  {% assign height = width | times: 20 | divided_by: 100 | times: 140 | divided_by: 100 %}
  <div class="item img-cover img-fixed {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}" style="background-image: url({% pic '{{ news.image }}' %}) width= '{{width | join: "px"}}'  height='{{height | join:"px"}}'">
  <h2>{{ news.text }}</h2>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4):

{% pic comes from a custom plugin. Can you name it ?

Joining string with liquid :

```
width= '{{width}}px'
```

or

```
width= '{{width | append: "px"}}'
```